# flexbox not centering with justify-content, div elements taking up too much space i'm guessing, but why?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I've been trying to get these objects to center and when I used an `<a href>` tag, I could see that I was able to click way away from the picture and still the link would activate.  I am assuming this means that the child containers are taking up 50% of the width each, despite only a tiny portion of the container being full.  Why is there blank space that is preventing me from aligning my objects?

RELEVANT HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="previous">
      <img class="containerimg" src="https://i.imgur.com/YgZ2GOl.png">
      <p>Previous Project </p>
  </div>
  <div class="next"> 
    <img class="containerimg"  src="https://i.imgur.com/s11MTLc.png"> 
      <p> Next Project</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

RELEVANT CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center;
}
.containerimg {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
}
.next {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.previous{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/daniel-albano/pen/zYGKZEw?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague, but I'm assuming that you want to center the `.previous` and `.next` divs.

Since both of these are using `display: flex` already, you simply need to add `align-items: center` to the .`previous` and `.next` classes to make them center **horizontally**. If you also want the content (the image and text) to center **vertically**, you'll need to add `justify-content: center`. Here's the result:

```css
.next {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.previous {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

If you're trying to make the images in those divs take up more space, you'll need to increase the `width` rule below. Since you commented that you need 100%, you'll need to change it to this:

```css
.containerimg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve this issue by adding "align-items: center" to your .next and .previous classes. The reason for this is that when you switch the flex-direction to column that also switches how align-items and justify-content work, essentially reversing them.

```css
    .next {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .previous{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I needed my images to contain 100% of the space and I needed to assign a width element to the child containers.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
   display: flex; 
   justify-content: center;
   width:100vw;
}
.previous, .next{
   width:30%;
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   align-items:center;  
}

img{
   width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="previous">
      <img class="containerimg" src="https://i.imgur.com/YgZ2GOl.png">
      <p>caption 1</p>
      
  </div>
  <div class="next"> 
    <img class="containerimg"  src="https://i.imgur.com/s11MTLc.png"> 
    <p>caption 2</p>
     
  </div>
</div>
```